# Program crashes on scanf("%x",&foo) when trying to input hex values

Tags: c++, hex, scanf

I need to input hex values, but when I try to execute this code, the program crashes. I have no clue what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static void print_hex(uint8_t*,int);

int main () {
    uint8_t *iv;
    iv = new uint8_t [32];

    printf("Insert hex string:");
    scanf("%x",&iv);

    print_hex(iv,16);

    return 0;
}

static void print_hex(uint8_t * str, int len) {
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        printf("%.2x", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no `new` in [tag:c] so you should not tag [tag:c] but the correct language [tag:c++].

Comment: %x in scanf reads integers in hex, and you're trying to store that into a character array.

Comment: _@Eduardo_ Why are you using `new` and `scanf()` with c++ at all?

Comment: The way you are using `scanf()`, you are causing it to leak the `iv` buffer you allocate beforehand. You are expecting the user to type in a memory address (and `%x` is not the current way to input a memory address, use `%p` for that) that is valid within the scope of the current process, and then you are trying to read 16 bytes from that address. This whole code reeks of code smell. What are you *really* trying to accomplish? To have the user type in 16 bytes that you then read in? Or do you want the user to type in something else? What?  Please be clearer about your actual requirements.

Comment: Never use `operator new`.  It is toxic.  Leave it quarantined in the allocators where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a pointer to a pointer, and thus undefined behavior occurs. To do it right you just need

```
int32_t iv;
if (scanf("%x", &iv) == 1) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%x\n", iv);
}
```

You are then treating the pointer as if it was a string and it's certainly not, so the code would invoke again undefined behavior.

You apparently need to learn pointers, or not. Because if you are planning to learn [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you probably need to stay away from pointers.

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) there are references, which are easier to understad and work with than pointers, and also you have stream operators, some of them standard would allow you to input the hex value without the need of the `&` operator or anything related to poitners.

Comment: I think that if you want to read & write C++ you need to be fluent with pointers even though the language has references.  Maybe it's not among the first things you need to learn, but I do think it needs to be pretty early on. Avoiding learning about pointers isn't realistic.